How to read with path completion on a command line application in Zig?
I'm trying to read the path for a file with std.io.getStdIn, but there is no path completion.
Here's how I'm doing:
const input = try io.getStdIn().reader().readUntilDelimiterAlloc(allocator, '\n', 1024);

This is reading my input but there is no path completion on the shell, which might make it easy to misspell long paths.

Tag [tag:shell] are missused here!

path completion is a feature of the shells, not of zig (you might be able to add it yourself, or though a lib, if any exists)
